# Angular elements bound to same function. Avoid multiple call on each digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

Given the following:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="val in vals">
      <div data-ng-class:{'myClass':isEngineOn(val)}>
          <span data-ng-show="isEngineOn(val)">yeah it's on</span>
          <span data-ng-show="!isEngineOn(val)"> standby</span>
          <button data-ng-disabled="isEngineOn(val)">Start engine</button>
      <div>
</div>
```

isEngineOn changes with websocket messages I receive from the server.

Is there a way to avoid evaluating isEngineOn, 4 times during each digest, per each value in the repeat? Something like initializing a variable or something?

Comment: When does isEngineOn change? Please provide isEngineOn code

Comment: everytime i receive a websocket msg from the server. I don't have the code, since the example is invented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just have a variable in the controller that holds the result, and update that variable when you receive an update from the server:

In your controller:

```
$scope.engineOn = isEngineOn();//also make sure to update from server whenever you need
```

Note that if your `isEngineOn()` function is no longer called from the view it doesn't need to be on the scope, it can be declared as a regular variable.

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-class="{'myClass':engineOn}">
      <span data-ng-show="engineOn">yeah it's on</span>
      <span data-ng-show="!engineOn"> standby</span>
<div>
```

**EDIT 2**: The `ng-init`, as you said, did not update on digest so I've taken a second approach.

I've taken the long way round, and created a corresponding array for your values and you can read from that:

```
  <div data-ng-repeat="val in vals" >
      <div data-ng-class="{'myClass':enginOn[val]}">
          <span data-ng-show="engineOn[val]">yeah it's on</span>
          <span data-ng-show="!engineOn[val]"> standby</span>
          <button data-ng-disabled="isEngineOn(val)">Start engine</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11007/).

Comment: That won't work, isEngineOn function will not be updated every time digest is called, engineOn will be initial value forever

Comment: @karaxuna Hence the comment I placed, and the text above saying to update that variable.

Comment: fair enough, the thing is, the function has a parameter which depends on an ng-repeat, i will edit the question, sorry for that.

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 About a million times in a million places :) What error do you get?

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 Wait, there might be an issue, I'll update in a sec.

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 Created a fiddle where it works: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11006/

Comment: The problem seems to be, ng-init is called once only, it is not called on every digest!

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 Please see my update. I created an array for you to read from, once you get an update from the server you can update it and that way everything stays happy.

Comment: I see. Well I guess I need that array, in the controller, i wanted to avoid modifying the controller, but very deserved accepted answer, thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with simple CSS and without calling the function in the spans. I think thats much more efficient than a JavaScript solution, especially when you have a repeat over many elements because you can save bindings:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="val in vals">
    <div data-ng-class:{'myClass':isEngineOn(val)}>
        <span class="showWhenOn">yeah it's on</span>
        <span class="showWhenOff"> standby</span>
        <button onclick="alert('Starting...')">Start engine</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.showWhenOn {
    display: none;
}

.myClass .showWhenOn {
    display: inline;
}

.myClass .showWhenOff {
    display: none;
}

.myClass button {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: silver;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/nr98ha97/)

Comment: that is good advice, the real case also contains some buttons which I have to disable though, and don't see a way of applying the disable property using css. I can, using the function <button data-ng-disabled="isEngineOn(val)"> StartEngine</button>, but i want to avoid it.

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 you can use the css property `pointer-events: none` for that

Comment: yes, but i can still click the button, even if the visual effect is like, you don't click it. btw i gave a thumb up, it's interesting what you're proposing, limit angular bindings by using css in a smarter way, i did not think about this

Comment: Nope, pointer-events does not change the way the button is displayed. This property controls the behavior of the button, so nothing will happen if you click on it.

Comment: well in my case it prints stuff, just the stuff i have in the data-ng-click, and it shows that the property applies (firebug).

Comment: Perhaps because the div in your example is not closed? ;) I created a fiddle for you, it is worḱing there: http://jsfiddle.net/pascalockert/nr98ha97/

Comment: You're absolutely right sir, the problem was I had the anchor inside a <li> element, and the click was on this <li> element.  pointer-events: none; does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can set watcher to variable that changes when you receive answer from server, for example:

```
scope.$watch(function(){ return <var that changes>; }, function(oldv, newv){
    if(oldv !== newv)
        scope.isEngineOn = <Calculate here>;
});
```

Then use:

```
<span data-ng-show="isEngineOn">
```

Comment: Better not to have a redundant watch, it's heavy on performance.